# QueryString & String Comparison

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I know how to do this in PHP, and it has been a good 15-20 years since I've used PHP or ASP.

How do you get "Test" to be displayed.  I have hard coded a sample in that works.  I need it to be dynamic based upon the query string.  I have given some examples of how I tried in the comments above the if statement.

Index.cshtml

```
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Display Data";
    string[] TableHeaders = new string[] { "Tender Number", "Project Name", "Closing Date", "Address", "City", "Province", "Postal Code", "Created By" };
}

<table class="tableContainer">
    <thead>
        @{ foreach (var head in TableHeaders)
            {
                <th class="tableHeader">
                    @head
                </th>
            }
        }
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{ if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var Data in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tableRow"><a href="?tender=@Data.TenderNumber">@Data.TenderNumber</a></td>
                        <td class="tableRow">@Data.ProjectName</td>
                        <td class="tableRow">@Data.ClosingDate</td>
                        <td class="tableRow">@Data.Address</td>
                        <td class="tableRow">@Data.City</td>
                        <td class="tableRow">@Data.Province</td>
                        <td class="tableRow">@Data.PostalCode</td>
                        <td class="tableRow">@Data.CreatedBy</td>
                    </tr>
                    //if (Context.Request.QueryString.Equals("?tender=" + Data.TenderNumber + ""))
                    //if (Data.TenderNumber.Equals(Context.Request.QueryString.Substring(8,5))
                    if (Data.TenderNumber == "2021-004")
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="8" class="tableRow">Test @Context.Request.QueryString</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Data_Grid.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace Data_Grid.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        List<ProjectList> pList = new List<ProjectList>();
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            //con.ConnectionString = Data_Grid.Properties.Resources.ConnectionString;
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=NAC16\SQL2016;Initial Catalog=Estimating;Integrated Security=True";
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            FetchData();
            return View(pList);
        }
        private void FetchData()
        {
            if(pList.Count > 0)
            {
                pList.Clear();
            }
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                com.Connection = con;
                com.CommandText = "SELECT [TenderNumber],[ProjectName],[ClosingDate],[Address],[City],[Province],[PostalCode],[CreatedBy] FROM [ProjectList] ORDER BY [TenderNumber] DESC";
                dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    pList.Add(new ProjectList() {
                        TenderNumber = dr["TenderNumber"].ToString(),
                        ProjectName = dr["ProjectName"].ToString(),
                        ClosingDate = dr["ClosingDate"].ToString(),
                        Address = dr["Address"].ToString(),
                        City = dr["City"].ToString(),
                        Province = dr["Province"].ToString(),
                        PostalCode = dr["PostalCode"].ToString(),
                        CreatedBy = dr["CreatedBy"].ToString()
                    });
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Figured it out:

     if (Context.Request.QueryString.Value.Equals("?tender=" + Data.TenderNumber + ""))

Comment: be careful with that... looks a bit unsafe security-wise.

Comment: This is going to be used internally within our company only.  If I wanted to be able to make it more secure, I'd hide the connection string in an include file?

Comment: you should be good for an intranet... I was referring to echo'ing untrusted user input: @Context.Request.QueryString